# Material UI theming: colors in styled components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building a blog with react and material ui. I have created a theme and have already customized it. Now I have some styled components in it, where I can choose the colors well, but this is not possible as with the "normal" components. Is there a solution for this or where is my mistake?
Here is my (abbreviated, relevant) code.

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { Button, createTheme } from "@mui/material";


  
const myTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            light: '#dfdeef',
            main: '#dcbe90',
            dark: '#000000',
            contrastText: '#ffffff',
        },
        secondary: {
          light: '#c7decb',
          main: '#a07051',
          dark: '#000000',
          contrastText: '#ffffff',
        },
        background: {
          default: '#f5f5f5',
        },
    },
    components: {
        MuiFab: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    background: myTheme.palette.primary.main,
                }
            }
        },
    },
});



const TagButton = styled(Button)(() => ({
    backgroundColor: myTheme.palette.primary.dark,
  }));

  



export { TagButton, myTheme };
```

I would like to define the colors in this way everywhere, but this does not work with MuiFab.

```
background: myTheme.palette.primary.main
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ThemeProvider from Material UI to provide the theme to your styled components. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { Button, ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material";

const myTheme = createTheme({
    // your theme configuration
});

const StyledTagButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
}));

const App = () => {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
            {/* Your other components */}
            <StyledTagButton>Click me</StyledTagButton>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already use the themeprovider in my app but I thought I could use the styled components directly in my theme.tsx so that I have all styles in one file. Is that not possible?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely define your styled components directly within your theme file for better organization. If you want to use the theme directly in the same file where you define your styled components, you can use the withTheme higher-order component provided by Material UI.